# Sync data using Firebase and Ace Editor

Tags: firebase

After watching a demo on Firebase, I jumped in and tried to worked on an idea, collaboration on the same document. Turns out they already have Firepad as an example, but I still wanted to work on my own to better understand how Firebase works.

Using jQuery and Ace Editor, I'm able to create new documents but I find it hard to update once I started integrating Ace.

But then I'm getting an error from firebase.js

```
too many recursions
```

Changing the data on Firebase Forge automatically reflects on my page, but I cant seem to push my changes back to Firebase. Any ideas on how you'd pull this off?

--- EDIT---

Here's a sample code for a better view of what I'm working on.

```
var fileRef = new Firebase('https://user.firebaseio.com/document/body');

var editor = ace.edit("codepad");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/php");

fileRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    var file = snapshot.val();
    editor.setValue(snapshot.val());
});

editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
    fileRef.set(editor.getValue());
});
```

Comment: Posting a jsfiddle or similar with your full code might help us help you.  If I Had to take a random guess, maybe you're getting into an infinite update loop: ace changes so you save it to firebase, which makes firebase change so you save it to ace, which makes ace change so you save it to firebase, etc...

Comment: Thanks Michael, here's something on jsfiddle. I'll be updating my post above to reflect this code. Actually we share the same hunch, the problem is how to i write it otherwise? http://jsfiddle.net/c78Nk/

Comment: I had trouble getting a simple ace example working, so I couldn't test your code. But to debug, I'd start by setting breakpoints or adding console.log statements to see what snapshot.val() and editor.getValue() are.

In theory, if you do a ref.set() with a value that is the same as what's already there, you won't get any event, so you should /not/ see an infinite recursion...  But perhaps that's not working for some reason.

As a hacky workaround, you could try wrapping your .set() call with "updating = true" and "updating = false" and then not call editor.setValue() if updating==true.